# Order  by case results in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have following query working :

```
SELECT
COUNT(id), AgeRange
FROM
(
select
id,
case
when age < 0 then 'less than 0'
when age >= 0 and age <=30 then '0-30'
when age >= 31 and age <=60 then '31-60'
when age >= 61 and age <=90 then '61-90'
when age >= 91 then '91+'
when age = null then 'NO INFORMATION'
else 'no catagory'
end AS AgeRange
from queue 
where DATE between '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
) T
GROUP BY
AgeRange;
```

Now my requirement is that, I want these result to be printed always in a sequence, first for less than 0, than for 31-60 and so on.

Even if get count 0 for any interval say 31-60. It should return 0 for that interval. Can anyone help.

Further clarification: what I want is if for any case I am getting zero count it should also print that.

In my table of database for this query it is not displaying the 'less than 0' case:

```
COUNT(ID) AGERANGE       AGERANGESEQUENCE
-------------- -------------- ----------------
     11139 0-30                          2
      2292 31-60                         3
       329 61-90                         4
      1078 91+                           5
       746 NO INFORMATION                6
```

Its not showing me the first row of count 0.

I want that too, so that I can get a well defined table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by that column - just add an

```
ORDER BY AgeRange
```

after the `GROUP BY AgeRange` clause:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(id), AgeRange
FROM
   ( ..... ) T
GROUP BY
    AgeRange
ORDER BY
    AgeRange
```

If that sequence doesn't work out for you, then you'd have to add a second `CASE` statement to define a `AgeRangeSequence` to your inner select and then order by that column:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(id), AgeRange, AgeRangeSequence
FROM
     (SELECT
          id,
          CASE
             WHEN age < 0 THEN 'less than 0'
             WHEN age >= 0 AND age <= 30 THEN '0-30'
             WHEN age >= 31 AND age <= 60 THEN '31-60'
             WHEN age >= 61 AND age <= 90 THEN '61-90'
             WHEN age >= 91 THEN '91+'
             WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'NO INFORMATION'
             ELSE 'no category'
          END AS AgeRange,
          CASE
             WHEN age < 0 THEN 1
             WHEN age >= 0 AND age <= 30 THEN 2
             WHEN age >= 31 AND age <= 60 THEN 3
             WHEN age >= 61 AND age <= 90 THEN 4
             WHEN age >= 91 THEN 5
             WHEN age IS NULL THEN 6   
             ELSE 7
           END AS AgeRangeSequence,
    FROM dbo.queue 
    WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN '01-Apr-2011' AND '05-May-2011'
   ) T
GROUP BY
    AgeRange, AgeRangeSequence
ORDER BY
    AgeRangeSequence
```

PS: in your `CASE` statement, you should check for `WHEN age IS NULL` and **not** use `WHEN age = NULL` since you cannot compare to `NULL` using the normal comparison operators!

Comment: thanx for the reply its working but not full filling my second requirement.. if count for any interval is 0 its not printing that row ...COUNT AGE_RANGE
----------- -------------
      11139 0-30
       2292 31-60
        329 61-90
       1078 91+
        746 no catagory                    this result not printed row for les than sero case

Comment: @PramodShivhare: typo: it should be `category` (not `catagory`)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT coalesce(t.idcount, 0),
       c.agerangetext
FROM   (SELECT 1, 'less than 0' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, '0-30'        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, '31-60'       UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, '61-90'       UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, '91+'         UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, 'NO INFORMATION'
       ) AS c(agerange, agerangetext)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS idcount,
                          agerange
                   FROM   (SELECT id,
                                  CASE
                                    WHEN age < 0 THEN 1
                                    WHEN age >= 0 AND age <= 30 THEN 2
                                    WHEN age >= 31 AND age <= 60 THEN 3
                                    WHEN age >= 61 AND age <= 90 THEN 4
                                    WHEN age >= 91 THEN 5 
                                    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 6
                                  END AS agerange
                           FROM   QUEUE
                           WHERE  DATE BETWEEN '01-Apr-2011' AND '05-May-2011'
                          ) t
                   GROUP  BY agerange) AS t
    ON c.agerange = t.agerange
ORDER  BY c.agerange
```

[Working sample](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60105/new)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a bunch of UNIONs:

```
SELECT 1, COUNT(id), 'less than 0'
FROM queue
WHERE age < 0 AND DATE BETWEEN '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
UNION
SELECT 2, COUNT(id), '0-30'
FROM queue
WHERE age BETWEEN 0 AND 30 AND DATE between '01-Apr-2011' and '05-May-2011'
UNION
...
```